# Creating a dictionary with keys having lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary of lists for the with 1 key having 5 values

```
{
  customer_id: [name, date of birth, location, phone number, age]
}
```

How can I do that by taking input during runtime? How to store a date as a value in a dictionary

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: You're not storing a date in the dictionary. It's in a list. For example, `data[customer_id] = ["name", datetime.datetime.now()]`

Comment: I have tried using nested dictionaries. But it should be dictionary of lists only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will help you:

```
d={}
customer_id=int(input())
l=[]
name=input()
date of birth=input()
location=input()
phone=input()
age=input()
l.append(name) 
l.append(date of birth) 
l.append(location) 
l.append(phone) 
l.append(age) 
d[customer_id]=l
```

Keep in mind that name, date of birth, location, phone and age, all will be treated as a string.